# GAE blobstore image upload . resp.sendRedirect("somepage.jsp") not working as expected

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine

> **Note** : **My basic Blobstore image upload works fine** ! (the sample
>   tutorials part) now I am customizing it for my college project and
>   facing some errors

these files are generated

WEB-INF\appengine-generated :
[image]

after this I have a code

```
resp.sendRedirect("onetimePassword.jsp");
```

but it is sending the page to

> ...:8888/_ah/upload/onetimePassword.jsp

and giving 
Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
and no error message on my console
[image]

**without the blobstore part the redirects are working correctly ! , how do I fix this ??**

---

more codes :

```
<form id="form_register" name="form_register" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/RegisterServlet") %>">

<input type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/*">
```

---

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>controller.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPON FURTHER CHECKING I understood this. *please correct me if i have understood anthing incorrect*

```
"<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/RegisterServlet") %>"
```

> sends you to /_ah/upload/blobfileinfo

and `resp.sendRedirect("onetimePassword.jsp")`
 use the current path of /_ah/upload and append onetimepass.jsp to it

---

```
resp.sendRedirect("/onetimePassword.jsp");
```

> FIXED THE ISSUE FOR ME